# Overriding == operator in C++

Tags: c++, overriding, comparison-operators

I am trying to override the == operator for a class, however the comparison seems to failing somehow. when I write the same as a function called **eq**(for example) no problem occurs.

```
class geo
{
    ...
        bool operator==(geo const& other)
        {
            if(_id != other._id) return false;
            if(!(name == other.name))return false; 
            if(is_primary!=other.is_primary)return false;
            for(int i = 0; i<6;i++){
                if(position[i]!=other.position[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
   ....
    private:
        int _id, is_primary;
        vector position;
        string name;

}
```

In main function:
...

```
geo* i= new geo(2.1, 2.82, 1, 0, 0, 180, 0, "Patient-1",1);
geo* j= new geo(2.1, 2.82, 1, 0, 0, 180, 0, "Patient-1",1);
if(i==j)
    std::cout<<"they are equal\n";
```

However when I run this, it says they are different for i and j. Any idea of where i do the stuff wrong ?

Edit: 
Thank you guyz at the comments. I just solved it; 
the code shown above works pretty ok. If course I was trying to simplify the code to make here paste something readable. So I am updating the code above to turn it into a problem so that future readers might see a better solution than I did, as well as I can learn more.

Comment: Please provide constructor declaration, for geo  ? and
 "vector position" is syntactically valid??

Comment: "Any idea of where i do the stuff wrong ?"  - yeah, there's a problem in the code you didn't show.

Comment: debug it with putting break point on each return false statement and check where you return false

Comment: The code as shown looks correct (assuming the `position` vector  always has exactly 6 items in it -- are you sure you didn't meant to use `i<position.size()` in your for-loop instead?).  Perhaps the two objects really are different?  You might want to check your constructors to verify that they really do set all the member-variables of the object correctly.

Comment: Btw you probably want to add the `const` qualifier to the end of your `==` operator-declaration (i.e. `bool operator==(geo const& other) const {...}`), otherwise you won't be able to check a const-tagged `geo` object for equality.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of 'position'? I think the == operator may be incorrect, which is leading to the array comparison returning true when it shouldn't.

Comment: guys I am sorry that I actually wrote a valid code here while simplifying it. I updated in a way that its problematic to learn your perspectives.

Comment: In the main function you are comparing the pointers of `i` and `j` instead of comparing the objects themselves. In reference to `position[i]!=other.position[i]`, you'd need to compare floating-point numbers with tolerance.

Comment: use `if(*i==*j)` instead

Comment: Are you coming from Java? You should almost never use pointers and `new` in C++.

Comment: @n.m. "You should almost never use pointers and new in C++" saying that can you clarify how it actually should be ? (assuming you are not speaking of anything related also to smart pointers.)

Comment: *When and if* you need *owning/managing* pointers you should use smart pointers. A raw pointer is not managing, and should be never initialised with `new` but always with an address of an existing object. Normally you just use objects. `geo i(2.1, 2.82, 1, 0, 0, 180, 0, "Patient-1",1);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing `i == j` you are comparing two pointers to `geo`, and not the objects they are pointing to. Since the pointers are obviously different, you get the result as such.

To actually compare objects, you need to dereference the pointers:

`if (*i == *j)`
`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if your geo class's comparison operator is a lexographical compare of its members.

You may be interested to know that you can use a `tuple` to unify all comparison operators by building a `std::tie` of the members in the appropriate order.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

class geo
{
public:
    template<class...Args>
    geo(Args&&...);

private:
    auto as_tuple() const { 
        // note: mentioned in lexographical order
        return std::tie(_id, name, is_primary, position); 
    }

    friend auto operator ==(geo const& l, geo const& r) -> bool
    {
        return l.as_tuple() == r.as_tuple();
    }

    friend auto operator <(geo const& l, geo const& r) -> bool
    {
        return l.as_tuple() < r.as_tuple();
    }

private:
    int _id, is_primary;
    std::vector<int> position;
    std::string name;
};


int main()
{
    geo i= geo(2.1, 2.82, 1, 0, 0, 180, 0, "Patient-1",1);
    geo j= geo(2.1, 2.82, 1, 0, 0, 180, 0, "Patient-1",1);

    if(i==j) {
        std::cout<<"they are equal\n";
    }

    if(i < j) {
        std::cout<<"i is less\n";
    }
}
```